# Allow winscp/filezilla through iptables and fail2ban

Tags: iptables, sftp, fail2ban

I just launched a website within my school community and woke up this morning to logs of someone trying to bruteforce into my server. I followed some guides on digitalocean to set up `fail2ban` and `iptables`, and am still able to ssh into the server using port 22.

However, I cannot seem to interact with the server over sftp. I have tried both winscp and filezilla and both seem to time out

For winscp I get this:

```
Host is not communicating for more than 15 seconds.
Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "will".

Authentication failed.
```

And with filezilla I get this:

```
Status: Resolving address of %website%
Status: Connecting to %ip%:21...
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
```

Also, `sudo iptables -S` returns this:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-apache
-N fail2ban-apache-noscript
-N fail2ban-apache-overflows
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache-overflows
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache-noscript
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A fail2ban-apache -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-apache-noscript -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-apache-overflows -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
```

Anyone have any idea? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Subsystem for sftp enabled in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file? The line might look like this:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server  (or your location of executable)
```

On another server (Debian/Ubuntu Jessie):

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```